# Resultant of two force vectors

Tags: vector

- Vector 1 is 80 degrees counterclockwise from the X axis and 150 Newtons in magnitude
- Vector 2 is 15 degrees counterclockwise from the X axis and 100 Newtons in magnitude

What is the resultant vector?

Surely there is already a way that *Mathematica* 11.3 can compute this without me having to apply the law of sines and law of cosines.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. First share what have you tried already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe the question speaks for itself. Two vectors, how to get the resultant without having to manually use law of sines and cosines. In other words isn't there already a mathematica function to do this?

Comment: Look up [`AngleVector`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AngleVector)

Comment: F1:=AngleVector[Quantity[100,"Newtons"][15,"AngularDegrees"]] F2:=AngleVector[Quantity[150,"Newtons"][80,"AngularDegrees"]] Is this right? Then what?

Answer (score 2):

Define the vectors (the units are irrelevant for the angle you want to obtain in the end):

```
v1 = 100 AngleVector[15 Degree];
v2 = 150 AngleVector[80 Degree];
```

and just add them:

```
vec = v1 + v2 // FullSimplify
```

> {25 (Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[6] + 6 Sin[10 °]), 
>    25 (-Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[6] + 6 Cos[10 °])}

or

```
N[vec]
```

> {122.64, 173.603}

The length is

```
Norm[vec] // FullSimplify
```

> 25 Sqrt[(-Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[6] + 6 Cos[10 °])^2 + (Sqrt[2] + 
>       Sqrt[6] + 6 Sin[10 °])^2]

```
N@Norm[vec]
```

> 212.552

You won't get a much simpler result [because 10° does not result in a simple radical](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(10+degrees)&js=off) so that

```
angle = VectorAngle[vec, {1, 0}] // FullSimplify
```

> ArcCos[(Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[6] + 6 Sin[10 °])/(
>    2 Sqrt[13 + 3 Sqrt[2] (-1 + Sqrt[3]) Cos[10 °] + 
>      3 (Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[6]) Sin[10 °]])]

can be expressed only approximately

```
N@angle
```

> 0.955763

which is in radians. It can be easily converted to degrees:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[N@angle, "Radians"], "Degrees"]
```

> Quantity[54.7612, "AngularDegrees"]

or simply

```
angle 180./Pi
```

> 54.7612

Comment: One could also use `v1 = AngleVector[{100, 15 Degree}]` etc.

Comment: corey979, Thank you for taking the time to show me how to work this in Mathematica. I would also like to say that your answer is indeed correct.                                                                                                                Carl Woll, your AngleVector Form is noted too. Thanks.